# Tomcat 9 - add an http header for content-dispostion = inline

Tags: http, tomcat, tomcat9

I have a brand new installation of tomcat 9. It is running a webapp called jasperreports. When a report is downloaded from a browser I want it to display in the browser so I want to add the http header content-disposition to the header. I am kind of new to tomcat, how and where can I add this? In a regular apache server, I would do the following to achieve the same result:

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header set Content-Disposition "inline"
</IfModule>
```

But in Tomcat, I am unsure how to add this header to the response.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you will need to edit $CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml to add a filter. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/Hory314/response-header-filter)